# Spring Data, updating MVC partial entity

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data

I'm new to Spring, Spring data and Spring MVC so I want to make sure I am not missing something.

I have a form for updating a User object, the form posts to a controller and the controller calls my service class that updates/add the entity using a UserDOA which extends CRUDRepository. I think this is a very basic test code.

The issue is that the form doesn't contain all the fields in my User class, so when the object is posted to the controller, only the fields that are contained in the form are populated and the entity fields that are not in the form are null. For example my user has 4 fields, firstname, lastname, age, password. The form only contains the first 3 fields so when the object is posted to the controller, the password field is null, that is as I expect. My issue is that if I then call save(entity) on my DAO it will update the user but that would include nulling the password field, which of course is undesirable.

Of course I could simply retrieve the original entity from the repository and merge it with only the fields that have been updated, but it seems to me this is a lot of work that would be very commonly required and typically spring has a solution to these types of generic tasks.

Did I miss something?

TIA

Comment: Can you show some of your code that helps understanding your problem?

Comment: Your suggested solution is the right one. What you're posting is not a User entity. It's a command that contains 3 fields of a User. Setting 3 fields is hardly a lot of work, and decoupling the commands you get from the actual entities is, IMHO, a good thing.

Comment: Thank you JB Nizet. I just wanted to make sure I'm not coding things Spring is already designed to take care of. 3 fields is indeed not a lot of works to transfer but this is just a test, in the real world the number of fields would be more significant.